# Command with percent symbols not running in crontab

Tags: cron

The following crontab does not work:

```
# TEST LINE DOES DOT RUN
*/1 * * * * /bin/echo 'test '`/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d` >> /tmp/test
```

I also tried starting it with:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

**Update:** I thought the backtick characters ` were the villains, but as the answer below clarifies the percentage % was the culprit!

Comment: Your test line will run only once each hour. That may not be what you intended for testing.

Comment: isn't the first the minute?# m h  dom mon dow   command

Comment: You are right.. I changed to */1 to make it run every minute.The cron is running fine. There is something with the commands. It seems to be the `/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d`, you need to escape each `%` with `\` according to [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab):

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: thanks! I will edit the question so that it fits the real problem.