# Cron, not working

Tags: cron

**Issue**

I have this cronjob.

```
5 12 * * * find /var/www/html -name "*.php" -o -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.css" | tar -cf /var/www/export/$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")-backup-fs.tar.gz -T -
```

But it is not working, even no errors came to configured email.

When I run this command manually, it works.

I tried set up the rights to `777`.

Where is the catch?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

Comment: What did you try to set 777 rights on?

Comment: @SorenA To folder `/var/www/export`.

Comment: See [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! Simple question, simple answer. I suspect that it could by in some character, but quite surprise about `%` char.