# Why won't this command run in cron?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, cron

I have this command

```
echo "$(date +"%T") $(sensors | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | head -1)" >> /home/me/temp_log.txt
```

that gets some sensor data and puts it into a file and I want to run it every half hour. It works fine in the stdin, but when I put it into my crontab file as such:

```
0,30 * * * * echo "$(date +"%T") $(sensors | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | head -1)" >> /home/me/temp_log.txt
```

it just doesn't run. Vim is highlighting weird after the % but I'm not sure if that's part of the problem or not.

Comment: See [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)

Comment: vim interpet the line as one string it doesnt understand command substitution '$()', you can use single qoutes inside subs. like this echo "$(date '+\%T') ...  same goes for grep, it will not affect the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `cron` doesn't offer full `bash`-like parsing. It's easier to:

```
0,30 * * * * /home/me/bin/mycron
```

where `/home/me/bin/mycron` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(date +"%T") $(sensors | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | head -1)" >> /home/me/temp_log.txt
```

And, since `cron` has its own idea of `PATH`, you might need to use a full path for the `sensors` command.