# Check if a cronjob still writes to a log file

Tags: scripts, php, cron, log

I want to define a cronjob like this:

```
@hourly /path/to/my/script.sh &> "/path/to/my/logs/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt)"
```

So it should write the output of the script to a log file. Now I want to make a second script (preferably with PHP) that reads all files in `/path/to/my/logs/` and sends the files via mail. It shouldn't be a problem to create such a script, but I wonder how I can detect if the cronjob that created a file is done and no longer writing to the file. I don't want to send a file that was created but the cronjob still writes to.

Is there a general way to detect that and also a way in PHP to detect that?

Comment: FYI: [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab). Also cronjobs are executed using /bin/sh by default - `&>` will not behave the way you expect unless you explicitly change the `SHELL`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a handy little tool like [the Crontab Generator](https://crontab-generator.org/) to build the job definition. To run a job hourly, you can do something like this:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/output/log_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).txt >/dev/null 2>&1
```

From there, you can have your PHP script use [the `filemtime` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the last time the file was modified. If the cron job takes X seconds to run and the output file has a modification date under X+60 seconds (or any number you're comfortable with), then you can have the script read the data and process it however you wish.

Comment: I have also thought about this, but the runtime of the script is variable and can last from a few seconds to several minutes. But if there is no better solution, I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, `crontab`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.