# right format of date command in crontab

Tags: 20.04, cron

I'm trying to output the current date in this format to a file using /etc/crontab. But crontab doesn't like this formatting. Changing sh to bash doesn't help.

my crontab:

```
* * * * * root echo "$(date +%F) - $(date +%T) - no sleep!" >> /home/thomas/1-18-WD/ami
```

expected output to the file:
2021-05-18 - 03:57:09 - no sleep!

it only works if I just do echo "$(date) - no sleep!"
The "+" is causing the problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with7 `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `+` character that's the problem here - it's the `%` character(s), as explained here:

- [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)

However you can simplify the command and avoid 2 calls to `date` **and** the `echo` by moving your text into the `date` format string directly, i.e. `date "+%F - %T - no sleep!"`

Inside a crontab, that needs to be written as:

```
* * * * * root date "+\%F - \%T - no sleep!" >> /home/thomas/1-18-WD/ami
```

Comment: date "+%F - %T - no sleep!" >> /home/thomas/1-18-WD/ami neither date "+\%F - \%T - no sleep!" >> /home/thomas/1-18-WD/ami doesn't work.

Comment: @ThomasHunter can you be more specific? please append `2>&1` to capture any error output to your file as well

Comment: @ThomasHunter also note that the username field (`root` in your example) is only required in the systemwide /etc/crontab file - if you are using a user-crontab via `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e` it is wrong and will cause the job to fail.