# CRON doesn't run

Tags: bash, cron, amazon-ec2

I had to reinstall a whole stack on an EC2 instance because a colleague mess up the previous one (not able to SSH anymore).
Long Story Short: New EC2 is running.

We have to run 2 jobs by a CRON job. Each script run perfectly of run manually.

`00 3 * * 1,3,5,7 cd /home/ubuntu/my/path/; ./ingest_daily.sh &> "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_ingestion.log)"`

But the script is never launched, no log file.

So I have added a dummy cron doing:

`*/1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/my/path/ ; echo "Hello World!" &> "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_test.log)"`

Nothing either.

`pgrep cron` shows me a PID so the daemon is running.

I have no idea where to look at it. I have already read some answers here but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `&>` is a bashism - cron's default shell is `/bin/sh` which will treat it as separate `&` and `>` (i.e. place the command in the background and redirect stdout). As well, `%` is special and must be escaped - see for example [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/434042/178692). FWIW I don't see a problem with `cd`

Comment: @steeldriver you are right about both `&>` and `\%`. If you want to write it as an answer so I can +1 you. Thanks