# 'sudo crontab -e' Jobs Are Not Running on Fresh Install of Ubuntu 21.10 (Gnu/Linux 5.13.0-30-Generic X86_64)

Tags: server, bash, scripts, cron, 21.10

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu.  I am trying to setup some cron jobs using `sudo crontab -e`

My crontab is as follows:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
# Task #1 - Start up local service for noips (dynamic DNS provider), and change permissions of mounted drive so another service can access said files
@reboot /usr/local/bin/noip2 && chown -R ikaros:plex /home/ikaros/mnt/ > /dev/null
# Task #2 - Shutdown the server every day at 0 10
0 10 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r +5 > /dev/null
# Task #3 - Dump postgreSQL databases to a file at 0 11
0 11 * * * (pg_dumpall > /home/ikaros/postgres_backups/"backup_$(date +%F)".sql) >> /home/ikaros/logs/pg_dump.log 2>&1
# Task #4 - Make sure only the last 5 backup files are stored on the disc every day at 0 9
0 9 * * * (cd /home/ikaros/postgres_backups/ && ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +5 | xargs -d '\n' -r rm -- ) >> /home/ikaros/logs/pg_clear_backups.log 2>&1
```

Task #1 seems to work fine.

Task #2 seems to work fine.

Task #3 NEVER runs, despite when I paste this command `(pg_dumpall > /home/ikaros/postgres_backups/"backup_$(date +%F)".sql) >> /home/ikaros/logs/pg_dump.log 2>&1` when logged in as user `ikaros`, it works fine.

Task #4 also NEVER runs, despite when I paste the command `(cd /home/ikaros/postgres_backups/ && ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +5 | xargs -d '\n' -r rm -- ) >> /home/ikaros/logs/pg_clear_backups.log 2>&1` while logged in as `ikaros`, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?  Any advice?

Much appreciated!

Comment: For #3, see [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)

Comment: @steeldriver, ok, I have just edited task #3 to now be `0 11 * * * (pg_dumpall > /home/ikaros/postgres_backups/"backup_$(date +\%F)".sql) >> /home/ikaros/logs/pg_dump.log 2>&1` -- I will let it run tonight and see the result.  Thanks so much.