# Cronjob not running - I tried many suggestions from StackEx - still nothing

Tags: command-line, cron

I'm about to descend into madness over a cronjob I'm trying to set up. I cannot for the life of me (after spending many hours/effort) figure it out, hope you can help.

I have a Python script at `/Server/Home/Paul/Sys+Tech/sortphotos/src/sortphotos.py` that takes some params and organizes files in separate/sub-folders.
**When I run this script directly it works just fine**

I've set up a crontab for the user owning the python script (paul) that looks like this, but does not work

```
* * * * * echo $(date) "cron works" > /var/log/testingcron
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /Server/Home/Paul/Sys+Tech/sortphotos/src/sortphotos.py -r --sort "%Y/%Y %m" /Server/Multimedia/Photo/+inbox_paul/ /Server/Multimedia/Photo/
#* * * * * /bin/bash /Server/Multimedia/Photo/organize-inbox.sh
```

#### some elaboration

- I've set `a+rwx` permissions on `sortphotos.py`
- I've added the full path to the python executable and full path to the script
- I've checked access/permissions of the source files
- I've tried to set up a `organize-inbox.sh` bash-script containing the full execute command as an intermediary to run the `sortphotos.py` (commented out third line), also with lost of permissions on the `.sh`.
  **This also works when directly running the `organize-inbox.sh`.**
- I've tried to set up the cron for the root user

I picked up some useful advice during my endless online searches, one of which was to test if cron is actually working by writing to a file. That's what the first cronjob is about. It writes a line in `testingcron` every minute, and every minute without fail I have a line with timestamp in said file. Unfortunately the second, and third command do not yield the desired result;

I'm looking forward to learning from you what I'm missing/messing up! Thanks, Paul

p.s. I'm running Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: You will need to escape the percent signs - see for example [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, however escaping the `%` did not work until now, I'm trying some other things around syntax (whole command in quotes) - I will update as soon as I know more. Also but the `escape`-fix should not be necessary when ran via the bash script but that doesn't work either (as far as my reasoning; cron just runs the `sh` and from there it's a shell script as any other, but i'm no expert) as you might have guessed :-)

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `journalctl -xe -u cron`, and redirecting the cronjob output/errors to a file (`> /tmp/cron.out 2>&1` or similar) that you can examine for clues

Comment: was doing exactly that. journalctl shows something i don't get: 
`sep 22 14:56:01 precision CRON[2769488]: (paul) CMD (/usr/bin/python /Server/Home/Paul/Sys+Tech/sortphotos/src/sortphotos.py -r --sort "%Y/%Y %m" /Server/Multimedia/Photo/+inbox_paul/ /Server/Multimedia/Photo/) ` i.e. the command without the escaping backslashes I definitely put in. 
I also tried wrapping the whole line in `back-ticks` . 
nothing; very strange

Comment: The command *should* be shown without the backslashes in the journalctl output (they force cron to treat the `%` characters as literals). If you omit the backslashes, you would see an *incomplete* command (truncated at the first un-escaped `%`)

Comment: I assumed as much, but nonetheless the journal shows the command has been executed but the files have not been sorted into their respective folders, as should have happened

Comment: I'm having one more go with the syntax, thank you for helping me so far, so wonderful

Comment: Please change the line to `/usr/bin/python /Server/Home/Paul/Sys+Tech/sortphotos/src/sortphotos.py -r --sort "%Y/%Y %m" /Server/Multimedia/Photo/+inbox_paul/ /Server/Multimedia/Photo/ 2>/tmp/sortphotos.log` and then check the `/tmp/sortphotos.log` file and report any errors you see. Also, you don't need `echo $(date) > file`, you can just do `date > file` directly, but that's not what is causing you problems.

Comment: Is there anything interesting about the cron job in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @terdon Thank you, I just made the change and will report back in a minute, in the meantime, thanks for correcting my original question, is there a quick way to accept your edits?

Comment: You're welcome. And no need to accept, they have already been accepted. The reputation system of the site allows users with more than 3k reputation to directly edit, and since I have more rep than that, my edits don't need approval.

Comment: @Jos: nothing special in syslog
@terdon some progress.
I get an error from the script: it lacks permissions to move the file(s)
Which I don't understand since I'm running the script as `user:paul` and it works, the crontab is for `user:paul` and the owner of the folder is also `paul`

Comment: dangit when inspecting the file permissions I see only `-rw-r--r--`. These files are 'uploaded' with Syncthing, so that might be the reason for the lack of permissions. But still, when running the python-script directly (and via `.sh`) everything works

Comment: I finally got it to work, turns out `other` did not have `write` permissions for the destination folder (+sub) - when I set this manually, everything worked. Still I'm not entirely happy with the setting/setup that needs write access for other to be able to run a cronjob that is set up under a specific user, maybe I'm wrong. For now, again; thank you all for helping me and (while doing) teaching me how to debug cron @terdon (`2>file`) and also @steeldriver for the syntax help. Cheers!

Comment: @PaulPetrutoni the crontab should be running under the same user, how did you set it up? Also, could you please post the solution as an answer so the system will show the question as "answered"?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the permissions for the destination folder were not in tune with the rest of the setup.

`root` was owner of the destination folder `2022` and all sub folders. Since the cron-job and the python script were set up for user `paul` which did not have write permissions for `2022` the script failed.
**After setting `chown` to `user:paul` for the destination folder the cronjob runs as it should**

Biggest takeaway; I should have checked permissions a lot better before posting, but thank you anyway for helping me understand cron (including `stderr` & `stdout`) for future needs.