# Automatic backups of MySQL database with Cronjob

Tags: mysql, backup, vps

I would like to backup my MySQL database with a cron job, but I cannot make it work.

This is the code that I am using:

```
0 2 * * * mysqldump -u root toko_db | gzip > /var/backup/toko_db_`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.sql.gz
```

Comment: See [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date section for the file name seems malformed. Perhaps you could try this:

```
0 2 * * * mysqldump -u root toko_db | gzip > /var/backup/toko_db_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).sql.gz
```

Remember to send that file to another location so that you have a recent backup in the event the entire server disappears.

Comment: thank for, answer . it work