# "tcpdump" command in "crontab" crashes immediately after running the "crontab" jobs

Tags: cron, tcpdump

I want `crontab` to start a `tcpdump` command, but `tcpdump` seems to crash immediately after running the `crontab` jobs. This is the command that I am trying to run:

```
@reboot  /usr/sbin/tcpdump -l enpls0 -G 3600 -tttt -vvv 'port 5000' -w /home/edward/dump-%H.pcap
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319531/why-is-crontab-not-starting-my-tcpdump-bash-script-capture Check out the link. Hopefully, some of those suggestions will help. Try to update the script.

Comment: It may not be the *only* issue, but you will need to escape the `%` in the filename in order for the `%H` to be processed as a timespec for the `-G 3600` file rotation option. See for example [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command with percent symbols not running in crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433866/command-with-percent-symbols-not-running-in-crontab)